# EF Core not including boolean column with default value in SQL INSERT statement

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have an entity in EF Core with a boolean property `IsActive`. I've configured this property to have a default value of `true`. However, when I try to add a new entity and set `IsActive` to `false`, the generated SQL INSERT statement omits the `IsActive` column, resulting in the default value of `true` always being set.

Here's how I've configured the property:

```cs
builder.Property(p => p.IsActive).HasDefaultValue(true);
```

And here's how I'm adding the entity:

```
var entity = new MyEntity { IsActive = false };
dbContext.MyEntities.Add(entity);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The SQL statement should include the boolean column with the value set to false.

Comment: Is the property a `bool` or a `bool?`/`Nullable<bool>`?

Comment: See the duplicate. This is an incredibly annoying bug (feature?) in EF.

Comment: I solved with bool? and added IsRequired in configuration, also opened bug (issue) in GitHub (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31538)

Comment: [Working with default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/miscellaneous#working-with-default-values). Pay attention to the Nullable backing fields for bool properties.